# iOS 13 status bar hidden for all iPhone types in landscape

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, statusbar, ios13

Our app has overridden `prefersStatusBarHidden` in its main view controller to return `false` for all situations. However, I'm getting different results while testing iOS 13.

When using the iOS 13 simulators in Xcode 11 (beta 6), they all hide the status bar (this is consistent with Apple's [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden)).

With the iOS 12 simulators, the X-model iPhones are hiding the status bar in landscape, but the other iPhone types are showing the status bar.

(Also to note, the `childForStatusBarHidden` property is not set anywhere in the app.)

Can anyone else confirm this behaviour? If not, what might be causing this inconsistency?

Comment: I also noticed that a blank iOS 13 project run on any of the iPhone simulators shows the status bar in portrait, but not in landscape. Wondering if this is an intentional design decision by Apple for iOS 13.

Comment: I have also noticed this with one of my apps.

Comment: Has anybody come up with a way to prevent this or are we constrained by Apple's whims?

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if your Settings are like this:
The TARGETS - General - Device Orientation include Portrait, LandScpaeLeft, Landsscape Right.

If your app isn't already in the app store, you can remove landscape support. If it's already online, I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?